# Проверка ссылки второго изображения товара

Tags: javascript, jquery

Существует ссылка вида `http://site.com/link/00/123m.jpg`. Она так же может быть `http://site.com/link/1/743m.jpg`, `http://site.com/link/2/689m.jpg` и т.д.

Это ссылки на первое изображение. Второе изображение идет такого вида:

1. `http://site.com/link/00/123m.jpg`
2. `http://site.com/link/00/123m_1.jpg`

То есть, добавляется "_1"

Как проверить наличие второго изображения при наведении на первое и в случае совпадения рядом добавить его? По сути, интересует, как разбить ссылку и вставить туда "_1".

Логика: `.hover()`, `this.attr('src')`, вставляем "_1", `if(!.error)`, `.after()`.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `str.split('_').length > 0 ? 'есть картинка' : 'нет картинки'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> По сути, интересует, как разбить ссылку и вставить туда "_1".

отвечаю на этот вопрос

```js
function addUnderline(link, number) {
  var dotIndex = link.lastIndexOf('.'),
      url = link.substr(0, [dotIndex]),
      ext = link.substr([dotIndex], link.length);
  return url + '_' + number + ext
}
console.log(addUnderline('http://site.com/link/00/123m.jpg', 1));
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо!